# numbered weekdays: find the k-th integer

Tags: python-3.x

The task I´m given is as follows:

> Days of week are numbered as:
>
> 0 — Sunday,
>
> 1 — Monday,
>
> 2 — Tuesday,
>
> ...
>
> 6 — Saturday.
>
> An integer K in the range 1 to 365 is given. Find the number of the day of the week for the K-th day of the year provided that in this year January 1 was a Thursday.

I´m struggling to create a general and user-friendly code for the given problem. Thanks for any help!

```
date=int(input('enter the K-th day: '))


if(day==0):
print("Sunday")
if(day==1):
print("Monday")
if(day==2):
print("Tuesday")
if(day==3):
print("Wednesday")
if(day==4):
print("Thursday")
if(day==5):
print("Friday")
if(day==6):
print("Saturday")
```

Answer (score 3):

We know that day 1 was a Thursday, this means we also know that day 8, 15, 21 and so on are also Thursdays. All these numbers have in common that if you divide them by 7, the remainder is 1.

Day 2 was a Friday, so day 9 and 16 are also Fridays. Divided by 7 the remainder for all Fridays is 2.

If you do this for all weekdays you will notice a pattern ;-) and if you check [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) you'll stumble across the Modulo operator.

This should point you in the right direction without spoiling the fun. If you need any additional help, just let me know and I'll reify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

here you go!

```
nday = int(1)    
dday=((3+nday)%7)    
print(dday)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add a little more detail to your answer? Answers with a little context are usually more helpful.